# Pytorch model function gives Error :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I trying to run below code in my image segmentation problem without CUDA as I don't have GPU. I have trained my model on CPU using pytorch but on prediction level I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Here's the code:

```
idx = 20
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/best_model.pt'))

image, mask = validset[idx]
image = image.unsqueeze_(0)
print(type(image))
# logits_mask = model(image.to(DEVICE).unsqueeze(0)) # (c,h,w) -> (1,c,h,w)
logits_mask = model(image) # (c,h,w) py-> (1,c,h,w)
```

The resulting error, from the output, is at line number 8:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-edf3f0fae49c> in <module>
      6 print(type(image))
      7 # logits_mask = model(image.to(DEVICE).unsqueeze(0)) # (c,h,w) -> (1,c,h,w)
----> 8 logits_mask = model(image) # (c,h,w) py-> (1,c,h,w)
      9 
     10 pred_mask = torch.sigmoid(logits_mask)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/segmentation_models_pytorch/losses/dice.py in forward(self, y_pred, y_true)
     57     def forward(self, y_pred: torch.Tensor, y_true: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
     58 
---> 59         assert y_true.size(0) == y_pred.size(0)
     60 
     61         if self.from_logits:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full Traceback? That would help in finding the source of the problem.

The error you are seeing is common, and is explained in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Answer (score 1):

`assert y_true.size(0) == y_pred.size(0)` erroring signifies that either `y_true` or `y_pred` are None, so you can try checking the types of `image, model(image), & mask` respectively.

IMO, this might be the root cause: `image = image.unsqueeze_(0)`

`unsqueze_` is an inplace operator, which means it will return nothing and change the tensor `image` inplace.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `print(type(image))`?

Since the error is nonetype for `model(image)` presumably the issues is with the model load or when you index the image in the following lines:

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/best_model.pt'))

image, mask = validset[idx]
```

EDIT: What's the output of print(image.size()) and print(image)?

t.size()

Comment: Value of print statement is : <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Comment: What's the output of print(image.size()) and print(image)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the mask as the second parameter to avoid NoneType.
`# logits_mask = model(image.to(DEVICE).unsqueeze(0), mask(DEVICE).unsqueeze(0)) # (c,h,w) -> (1,c,h,w) #or# logits_mask = model(image, mask) # (c,h,w) py-> (1,c,h,w)`